# Trouble with redirecting to an absolute_uri

Tags: django

I'm attempting to redirect to a full url

current url is an absolute_uri

```
currenturl = request.GET.get('currenturl') #lets say this resolves to http://www.google.com/
return redirect(currenturl)
```

This sends me to an 404 error page as it's trying to resolve the following url

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/calendar/delete/15/'http://www.google.com/'
```

Comment: You should prepend this with two slashes, to make it clear that this is the root URL, so `redirect('//google.com')`.

Comment: How do i write this with return redirect(currenturl)? I don't want to hard code the domain name as you've done in your example. thanks!

Comment: you prepend it with two slashes, so `redirect('//' + currenturl)`.

Comment: Error. Sends me to http://%27http://www.google.com'

Comment: That is likely because you added a space to the `'//'`?

Comment: nope. return redirect('//'+currenturl) is what i have

Comment: hold on, it looks like `currenturl` contains *single* quotes (as in it is not `"google.com", but `"'google.com'"`). So there is a problem with the GET parameter as well.

Comment: ah, thanks! I'll have a look at this. I guess i'll strip off the first and last value of the string and then try it.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the first and last single quote., so now it's forwarding me to http:// http //google.com (i added two spaces as SO was resolving this to a url and removing the duplicate http)

Comment: Fixed it. I just needed  return redirect(currenturl) with the two single quotes removed from the absolute uri that I passed into the currenturl variable in my template. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was passing the absolute uri in the template into the currenturl with single quotes around it. I had to remove the single quotes.